# Windows 10, choosing a desktop background for each screen when there is only 5 images shown under "Choose your picture"

Tags: windows-10, display

I have a setup where I have **6 screens**. But I was looking at having a different background image on each screen.

I know of the option where you add an image, then right click it and "Set for Montior X". This works for 5 of my screens but when you add another image it moves the last image in the list out.

**So I can only ever have 5 background images at any given time.**
[image: Only the most 5 recent will show]

**Is there a way in the registry to set this? Or am I going to have to look at this is programmatical way?**

*[Third party tools are not an option as this is on a restricted machine]*